# Check Minimum Maximum Number Based on the Hidden Textbox

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to validate the value in textbox1 if it exceeds the value in textbox2 which is hidden in the page.

I've initially made a code that will check the static maximum value of 100, however the maximum value is dynamic and depends on the value in textbox2

My PHP/MYSQL Code:

```
$sql_stmt = "SELECT user_val, max_val from table1";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql_stmt);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

/** JS for validating input in textbox1 **/
echo "<script>";
echo "function minmax(value, min, max) 
{
if(parseInt(value) < min || isNaN(parseInt(value))) 
return 0; 
else if(parseInt(value) > max) 
return 0; 
else return value;
}
";
echo "</script>";

/*** Textbox1 ***/
echo "<input type='text' onkeyup='this.value = minmax(this.value, 0, 100)' />";

/*** Textbox2 ***/
echo "<input type='hidden' value=".$row['max_val']." />";

}
```

The code is currently limited into max value of 100, I want it to vary based on the value in textbox2

Comment: What kind of validation you want to achieve? if the max number of textbox2 is greater than the textbox1, should the snippet prompt a message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `id` property to the hidden textbox as:

```
echo "<input id='maximumTextBox' type='hidden' value=".$row['max_val']." />";
```

then there is no need to pass the `maximum` value to `minmax` you can echo this instead of your function:

```
function minmax(value, min)
{
    // get the maximum value from the hidden textbox using the id above.
    var max = parseInt(document.getElementById('maximumTextBox').value);

    value = parseInt(value);
    if(isNaN(value) || value < min || value > max) 
        return 0; 
    else
        return value;
}
```

assuming that `min` is static. If you want to dynamically load `min`, you can do it the same as for `max`.